# AngularJS HTTP.get not fired/displayed in network tab

Tags: angularjs, get

When firing a http GET request with AngularJS multiple times the .then callback is called and there is a response but there is no request displayed on the network tab of my browser and the content of the response is wrong (content of the previously fired request). I assume it's some AngularJS/browser caching problem since when its cached on the backend the request would be displayed. I tried several things like disabling the cache but nothing helps. Could it has something to do that the promise of the http request is returned from a factory?

```
angular.module('eventLogServiceApp', [])
    .factory('eventlog.service', ['$http', createEventLogService]);

function createEventLogService($http) {
  return {
      getNotable: $http.get('https://myurl.com/api/endpoint')
  }
}

angular.module('myApp')

.controller("AdminEventLogController", ['$scope', 'TranslationService', 'eventlog.service', function ($scope, trans, EventLog) {
    $scope.getNotable = function() {
        EventLog.getNotable.then(function success(response) {
            $scope.notable = response.data.length;
        }, function error() {
        });
    };
 }])
```

I found out if I wrap the promise in a function the request is displayed in the network tab. I don't know why this works but it does. Example shown below:

```
angular.module('eventLogServiceApp', [])
    .factory('eventlog.service', ['$http', createEventLogService]);

function createEventLogService($http) {
  return {
      getNotable: function(){
         return  $http.get('https://myurl.com/api/endpoint')
      }
  }
}

angular.module('myApp')

.controller("AdminEventLogController", ['$scope', 'TranslationService', 'eventlog.service', function ($scope, trans, EventLog) {
    $scope.getNotable = function() {
        EventLog.getNotable().then(function success(response) {
            $scope.notable = response.data.length;
        }, function error() {
        });
    };
 }])
```

EDIT: Added controller/factory

Comment: A request is a request, and is shown as such in network panel - even if it is served from browser cache only.

Comment: Are you sure to call function that does this request?

Comment: I added the code for the controller and for the factory. Yes im sure that the function is called since if I debug I see the response of the successCallback.

Comment: Sure to don't have any filters in your Network tab?

Comment: @Zooly yes I am sure.

Comment: To start with, did you add any dumps in the JS console to verify if this function is called at present and check if the end point you are using is correct as well. Just do a clear cache and try once, depends on the browser you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap your logic into a function and return it there, otherwise it will be loaded only once on initial request.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this was caused by not wrapping the logic into a function. That means once using getNotable a variable is declared a request is fired and getNotable will be filled with the response. Using getNotable another time does not trigger a new request. Instead the already stored response is returned. I fixed it by wrapping the http Request into a function and returning the promise.

```
getNotable: function () {
        return $http.get(Routing.generate('epubli_api_get_eventlog_notable'));
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you using ? did you try it on several browsers ?

are you sure you don't filter the network requests ?

Comment: I've tried chrome and firefox and it has nothing to do with filters... I think it has something todo with returning the raw promise.

Comment: Try returning the data from your service instead a raw promise, maybe this is the case...

Another option (not sure this is what causing the problem..) try to remove the function name from you success callback..

Just use :

.then(function(data){
   $scope.noteble=data.length;
});

Comment: It should not make a difference to remove the function name. It should not touch the functionality to use an anonymous function. Its actually fixed by wrapping the factory variables into a function and return the promise like shown above in the edited part.